# SMART test failed, but all attributes is OK

Tags: hard-disk, smart

I've been experiencing problems with my HDD, so I ran a self-test on it.
As you can see, the test failed, but all individual attributes are OK. How do I know what the problem is with the drive?

[image: 1]

Comment: have you tried using the commandline to see if you can spot the issue? Other than that, the only thing that stands out there are the 3 "pre-fail" items.  Check there for additional info.

Comment: Honestly, I'm pretty lost among all the drive-health related commands and how they work, so no, I didn't use any commands yet.

Comment: The top right line says self-test failed "(read)". This doesnt sound good. From the command line you can get fuller output with `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` assuming your disk is `sda`. You can also run another short self-test with `sudo smartctl -t short -a /dev/sda`. It runs in the background. It will tell you to wait, probably about 2 minutes, for the result, which is simply another `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`.

Comment: Please post `sudo smartctl -a /dev/device output`.

Answer (score 0):

The most important factor is any (unspecified) problems, rather than the SMART stats. It's possible for a disk to fail, even though SMART says its almost perfect.

This is the time to make sure you have a backup of important data. You might consider the purchase of a SATA SSD and copy all your data to it.